# Can you create Telegram Channels/Groups using the API?

Tags: telegram, php-telegram-bot

I am hoping to use the Telegram API to create channels and groups. Also hoping that these can be set from the API, such as Private or Public channels, etc.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a channel/group using the [Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots), then you can't.
But you can create a channel/group using the [Telegram Apps API](https://my.telegram.org/apps).